# Python requests module file

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using a third party tool which uses a basic python installation but can compile new python modules on its own. All it needs is a .py file which can be compiled. Somehow, I am not able to locate a readily available requests module file which has the python code within it. Is it possible to guide me to any such resources. I have checked the github link from the requests official page: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests but I'm confused as to which file to clone. My best guess is that its the *init*.py file but I'm not sure.Any guidance on this would be helpful-

Please refer the screenshot below; I have highlighted the folder which I presume has the correct compileable python files needed for requests. If this is not the right folder please share your suggestions-

[download page from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fapPE.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Requests is package, there is no unified file that can be fetched/cloned and compiled. You need to fetch and compile all files.

Comment: Thanks @Arnial. I have edited my response to show which folders in github I'm talking about. Please check if this helps you suggest an answer-

Answer (score 0):

you could do `pip install requests`

If you dont have PIP installed then you can install it from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

and then can do `python get-pip.py`to install pip

alternatively you could also look at `easy-install`

Comment: Hi @saurabh baid pip will install the module in my system's installation of python. The third party tool I use doesn't use my local python installtion but has a different folder(nested under its main executable directory in windows) which require a .py file to be compiled.

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh yes `PIP` comes bundled with latest installation of Python, So did `pip install requests` solved your probelm?

Comment: pip install wouldn't help me. I needed the exact source python file and it worked for me(on the third party tool). I think I can now consider my question answered